# iOS Fastlane deployment (TestFlight) - how to include BETA demo credentials?

Tags: testflight, fastlane, fastlane-deliver, fastlane-pilot

We’re starting to use [Fastlane](https://fastlane.tools) for automated deployment, and it’s a very impressive toolset.

One mystery, though: 
When submitting a **BETA** build to Apple’s TestFlight, how do you pass in the **Demo Account** credentials (username and password)?  The docs don’t seem to say.

There seem to be a couple of clues here:
https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/spaceship/lib/spaceship/test_flight/beta_review_info.rb
https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/spaceship/spec/test_flight/app_test_info_spec.rb

And there does seem to be a way to pass in this info for actual App Store submissions:
https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/deliver/Deliverfile.md [see *app_review_information*]
... but not for TestFlight betas.

How do you do the equivalent for BETA uploads?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Appfile`, `pilot` use it like `deliver`

Here is the doc.
https://docs.fastlane.tools/advanced/#control-configuration-by-lane-and-by-platform

My Appfile for ex. is:

```
app_identifier ENV["app_identifierEnterprise"] # The bundle identifier of your app
apple_id ENV["accountAppleId"] # Your Apple email address
team_name ENV["teamNameEnterprise"]
team_id ENV["teamIdEnterprise"]

for_platform :ios do

    for_lane :releaseBeta do
        app_identifier ENV["app_identifier"]
        apple_id ENV["accountAppleId"]
        team_name ENV["teamName"]
        team_id ENV["teamId"]
    end
end
```

I use `.env` (a file to set this variables), but you just need to replace ENV[""] with "ValueYouWant"

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I never had been able to get this to work.